# Image not visible on webpage using create react app?

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

I have created a web app using create-react-app. Everything was going fine, but once I mapped images there occurred the issue. The mapped images are not visible on the webpage instead alternative text is written. I have attached a snapshot of it. Anyone help to solve this issue, I am new to React.[image]

Comment: This is kinda like an https://xyproblem.info/ you need to share more information about the issue and related code.  You likely won't get a solution with what you posted as you have given us your perspective of the problem not information of the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally if in the img component you already have the brackets then you don't need another bracket in the variable name:

For example if your img code was

```html
<img src={coverImage} />
```

then in your Data.js you would only need to put it as `coverImage: swim` , removing the brackets. This is because in JavaScript, importing a file gives you a string value which is a path that you can use as reference to your code. Hence, why you don't need another bracket, because `swim` here will return something like `swim.gibberish.png`. And since the src prop on an img tag already takes strings, you don't need another pair of brackets. More on this [here](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-images-fonts-and-files/)